# How can I composer update on OpenShift?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, openshift, slim

I am trying to use [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) on [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) with a free node. I can run `composer update` from the SSH sessions without any problem.

The only problem is every time I want to commit files through *git* I have to go to the console and run `composer install` again. My question is there is any easy way to workaround this? I tried a BASH script in */project/.openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy* but the server is not creating the vendor folder under runtime/repo

Comment: `but servers are constantly changing and that is not possible now` I was not able to understand the reason. In my deployment I have a `post_deploy` (+x) script inside .openshift/action_hooks folder containing `cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR && composer install`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always do it via [action hooks](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-action-hooks.html):

Inside my project directory I have a script called by `/project/.openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy` where **post_deploy** is a bash script.
Here goes what I have been using:

```
#!/bin/bash

export MY_PHPCOMPOSER=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar

# if composer not exists, download
if [ ! -f $MY_PHPCOMPOSER ]; then
    cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
    echo "Downloading composer..."
    php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php 
fi

$MY_PHPCOMPOSER -n -q self-update
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR 
# install
php -dmemory_limit=1G $MY_PHPCOMPOSER install
```

So **post_deploy** script will perform every time which you push your repo to openshit. It work like a charm!

## Side note

> Since not always the OpenShift composer's version is updated it's safe
>   to download a new composer copy and use it.
>   Also, don't forget adjusting permissions settings.

Helpful links

- [Openshift builds](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#openshift-builds)
- [Openshift Default Build Lifecycle](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#default-build-lifecycle)

Comment: I added a script before, the problem is that vendor is not being created in the /app-root/runtime/repo folder

Comment: I don't want to run "composer install" every time I commit files

Comment: Sure you have been doing something wrong. Also you don't want to run "composer install"  but you MUST to do it every time you push your repo. It is how to openshift work and you can't change that!

Comment: composer install supposed to be included in the .openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy, but still is not creating the vendor folder.

Comment: Found the error instead of git update-index --chmod=+x I just +x my local post_deploy. thank you for your help.

Comment: Had the same issue as @cardeol . fixed with perms

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer is late but according to the Openshift [documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-markers.html) you can enable `composer install` after each build by just creating a marker file:

```
touch .openshift/markers/use_composer
```