# composer self-update on Openshift not giving permission?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, openshift

when I run composer-self-update in Openshift I get the error below. I searched for a while but couldn't understand the solutions properly like this one - [How can I composer update on OpenShift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026031/how-can-i-composer-update-on-openshift)

[Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]
  Filesystem exception:
  Composer update failed: the "/var/lib/openshift/.cartridge_repository/redhat-php/0.0.28/usr/bin/composer.phar" file could not be written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31027824/1739852) in the question you linked does a pretty good job of explaining it if you follow the links, but I'm happy to try and explain it further for you.

Openshift supports [action hooks](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/action-hooks.html) which are scripts that are triggered to run at the appropriate git phase that you link them to.

To use the solution they suggest, you need to:

First; create a directory called `.openshift/action_hooks` inside the root directory of your project (e.g `mkdir .openshift/action_hooks`) - by placing it in the root directory it would map like this `myproject/.openshift/action_hooks`

Second; you now need to create a **bash script** called **post_deploy** inside the `action_hooks` directory that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

export MY_PHPCOMPOSER=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar

# if composer not exists, download
if [ ! -f $MY_PHPCOMPOSER ]; then
    cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
    echo "Downloading composer..."
    php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php 
fi

$MY_PHPCOMPOSER -n -q self-update
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR 
# install
php -dmemory_limit=1G $MY_PHPCOMPOSER install
```

You should now have a script that maps like this in your project; `myproject/.openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy`

Now every time you push to your repo in openshift it will execute that script and effectively run `composer install`.

If you have any trouble then be sure to check out the comments on that answer for a local permissions change you may need to make.

If you get stuck along the way then please comment or ask a new question and we can help you work through it.

Comment: @Al-aminNowshad It will download composer if it isn't installed or update it if it is

Comment: I guess the script is not executed.